# Passing 2D Array to from C# to Managed C++

Tags: c#, clr, managed-c++

I have this function in CLI/managed C++ DLL

```
void Sim1::GetRes(array<double^,2>^ param1)
```

And I call this function from C#

```
 double[,] param1 = new double[1000,2000];

 // fill the param1 array with values
 ...

 Sim1 sim1=new Sim1();
 sim1.GetRes(param1);
```

And I get this compiler error

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'double[*,*]' to 'System.ValueType[*,*]'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing multidimensional array from C# to C++ DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004455/passing-multidimensional-array-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll)

Comment: Delete the ^ from double, it is a value type.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! It works, please add the answer so I can choose your answer.